# How to rename xhtml in epub?

Tags: node.js, pandoc

I am using Node.js and pandoc. This is used to convert docx to epub.  Epub has predefined xhtml files.

I want to change xhtml file name. Any options to give pandoc exexcution?

Any one assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to change the xhtml file names inside the epub? why would you want that, they're invisible to the epub user... for other epub options, see http://pandoc.org/README.html#epub-metadata

Comment: As per my requirement, i need to change.  is it possible to change the name using pandoc(options parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

No, currently this is hardcoded.

You would have to fork the [Pandoc Github repo](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/) and adjust the [showChapter function in the EPUB Writer](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/EPUB.hs#L919).